# Imake not picking up header files

Tags: ubuntu, make

I am building some software, which is currently unsupported, that uses Imakefiles. The software does have a Imake.tmpl file. It is located (relative to the top directory) in config/cf/Imake.tmpl.

As the software has subdirectories containing other Imakefiles I typed (following [this man page](https://www.x.org/archive/current/doc/man/man1/xmkmf.1.xhtml)):

```
 xmkmf -a . .
```

The first dot is for the top directory and the second dot is for the current directory.

I got this error:

```
 mv -f Makefile Makefile.bak
 imake -I./config/cf -DTOPDIR=. -DCURDIR=.
In file included from Imakefile.c:34:0:
./config/cf/Imake.tmpl:33:0: fatal error: site.def: No such file or directory
 #include <site.def>
 ^compilation terminated.
  imake: Exit code 1.
  Stop.
```

The site.def file does exist and it is located under config/project/site.def.

This is the content of the Imakefile.c that is generated by imake. This file is removed when imake finishes execution, but it can be retained by creating a link to that file.

```
/* imake - temporary file */
#define DefaultOSName Linux 4.13.0-36-generic x86_64
#define DefaultOSMajorVersion 
#define LinuxDebian     4
#define LinuxInfoMagic  5
#define LinuxKheops     6
#define LinuxPro        7
#define LinuxRedHat     8
#define LinuxSlackware  9
#define LinuxTurbo      10
#define LinuxWare       11
#define LinuxYggdrasil  12
#define DefaultLinuxDistribution LinuxDebian
#define DefaultLinuxDistName Debian
#define HasGcc 1
#define HasGcc2 1
#define HasGcc3 1
#define GccMajorVersion 5
#define GccMinorVersion 2
#define INCLUDE_IMAKEFILE </tmp/IIf.j7V6mk>
#define IMAKE_TEMPLATE "Imake.tmpl"
#include IMAKE_TEMPLATE
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know enough about `imake` to give a good answer, but it's clear that it looks in the wrong directory for `site.def`, or that this file is located in the wrong place. As an unqualified hack, try creating a symbolic link in `config/cf` called `site.def` that points to `config/project/site.def` (or copy the file there), just to see what happens.

Comment: @Kusalananda - Great piece of advice ! That worked !! When I did that it reported a whole bunch of other files that were missing. I am moving those one by one !!!

Comment: @Kusalananda You can write this up and I will upvote and accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: I'm not a regular user of `imake` and I don't *really* know much about how that build system is *supposed* to work.

It is clear from the error that `imake` is looking for files to include under `config/cf`, but that the `site.def` file is located in `config/project`.

A hack would be to either symbolically link the `site.def` file from its current location to `config/cf`, or to make a copy of the file in that location.

This is a hack though, and I'm sure that the software that you are building can be built correctly without it.  You should consult the software's documentation.  It may be that `xmkmf` needs to be run in another directory, or that one of the `Imakefile` files could easily be modified to add an additional `-I` flag to the project.